# php, form using the same page after submittion

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I'm wondering what's the easiest way to make let's say a form with user/pass and submit button with php but after you submit it goes back to the same page instead of going to another php page.

I'm thinking of if/else statement but a bit confused how to set it after lots tries but still not getting the result wanted

*weird I did all those you guys said before I posted..but...>.<"*
let's say just something simple like this...

but I also want to set if nothing is entered then sumbit is clicked there'll be an error....should be something easy but I don't know why I can't seem to figure it out

```
<?php
function userPass()
{
    echo "<form method='post' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='user' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='pass' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Login' />";
}
    if(empty($_POST["user"]))
    {
        userPass();
    }
    if(!(empty($_POST["user"])))
    {
        if($_POST["user"] == "comp")
        {
            echo "Welcome comp";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong user";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is "result wanted"?

Comment: post some attempt of your code. we'll try to fix that...

Comment: set the form action to `""`

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are right; you only need to send the user back around to your current page in the "`action`" property. You can test to see if they did so using "`isset`".

Something that I'm surprised hasn't been mentioned yet is that your input is not being sanitized, and you're setting yourself up for disaster. **Huge** injection vulnerability in your action attribute:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

If you don't sanitize this, then someone can just modify the URL that they see and your poor PHP script won't know any better than to process that as your `SELF` constant.

In other words, you absolutely *must* use an `htmlspecialchars()` function to html-encode that parameter. With that, your `action` should look more like `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`.

Comment: This is quite irrelevant to the question, isn't it?

Comment: @Apostolos It's quite relevant to his use case, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

if current page is index.php, use index.php in form tag as value of action.

like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
</form>
```

u can check for submitted form by putting:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
...
}
```

at top of page

Comment: Setting action to PHP_filename (e.g. index.php) goes w/o saying of course, so it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just use below syntax

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

You can check whether post is set using isset() method.

Comment: Not w3c conform!
Bad value '' for attribute 'action' on element 'form': Must be non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code that I created to control learning the required input fields satisfy the requirements. when this is so, the data will be sent to the database. if it does not meet the requirements, there will be a message may be shown at the top of the page

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submitform'])) {   
}
else
{
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['mobile'] = $_POST['mobile'];
$_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];
$_SESSION['place'] = $_POST['place'];
$_SESSION['street'] = $_POST['street'];
$_SESSION['housenumber'] = $_POST['housenumber'];
$_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];

if (empty($_POST['firstname']) or empty($_POST['lastname']) or empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['mobile'])or empty($_POST['telephone']) or empty($_POST['place'])
or empty($_POST['street']) or empty($_POST['housenumber']) or !isset($_POST['gender']))
{
    echo "Sending denied";
}
else
{       
    require 'database.php';

    header('Location: succes.php');
}  ?>
```

I hope this is helpful information for you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php function userPass() {
    echo "<form method='post' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ">";
    echo "<input type='text' name='user' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='pass' /><br/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Login' />"; }
    if(empty($_POST["user"]))
    {
        userPass();
    }
   *if(!(empty($_POST["user"])))*
    {
        if($_POST["user"] == "comp")
        {
            echo "Welcome comp";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Wrong user";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

*This part of your code is wrong, you should type : if(!empty($_POST["user"]))*

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

This is exactly how you work with your form to reload the page when click the submit button inside this form.

**ADDITIONAL:**
Add `required` to all input you wanted to be required or check if it's empty.

Comment: could you provide some more information why this is a valid answer?

Comment: That exactly how you make your form.

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
```

or you could just do this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Thank you ....

Answer (score 0):

You can define in the form submission:

```
<form method=get action=index.php >
```

You can also leave action out altogether, and it will automatically post/get to that same file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all have missed the actual question, i.e. if there is a way to **stay in the same page** after submitting a form. The answer is **NO**. Once you submit a form -- whether you use the POST or GET method, and of course assuming that you are using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or empty action, etc. -- **a new page is opened automatically**. This holds at least for PHP. (I have tried a lot of different ways using XAMPP.) I don't now about other scripting languages.