# HTTP Error. Invalid Method

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton']))
{

$con = mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO app (fname, lname) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";


}

mysql_close($con)
?>



<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
App Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
App ID: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a basic form where I want to keep the user on the same page after submission.

I used this tutorial

[php form - on sumbit stay on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333901/php-form-on-sumbit-stay-on-same-page)

to help me, but I get:

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Can someone tell me what mistake I made?

Comment: What webserver are you using?