# Is model and view have direct relationship in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a view file view.php .Have following code.

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="profession_name" />
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Profession" onClick="add_profession" class="btn btn-success" />
    </form>
```

and i have model file Model_model.php.Have following code.

```
<?php 
class Model_model  extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
}
    function insert_data(){
        $data =  array(
            "profession_name" => $_POST['profession_name']
        );  
        $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
    }   

}?>
```

Is it possible without using controller i directly access form value in model?

Comment: whats the point to go with `MVC` architecture ?

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For best practices you would want to handle this with a MVC approach where all form information etc is sent from the view to the controller, handled and processed in the controller and then passed to the model for access to the db.

However, you can access the model in the view exactly like you would in your controller:

```
<? $this->model_model->insert_data(); ?>
```

And you can get post values from a form on the same page by using the method shown in this answer: [php form - on submit stay on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333901/php-form-on-submit-stay-on-same-page)